# Can we store incoming call in to local database in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, phone-call

I am developing a dialer application in which I want to store incoming call in local database in my application. After that I want to show the incoming call data on tableview. Is it possible to access incoming call in iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried it with CoreTelephone framework. It has methods for recentcalls which contains CTCall objects which have id and state of the call. You can explore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible to track and record incoming phone calls in iphone sdk. If you do this with some private API your app will get rejected from app store.

Comment: any alternate solution for that